# My Expression<Func<Product, Bool>> function is not returning the variable value, but instead value.(c__DisplayClass12_7).value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, expression, func

I'm creating custom expressions in order to put them into dynamic LINQ Where clauses using PredicateBuilder and my Expression function is not returning variable value, but instead the names of the variables or something else.

This is a snippet of the GetRule Expression Function:

```
public static Expression<Func<Product, bool>> GetRule(Rule rule)
{
       var value = rule.value;
       if (rule.type == "number")
       {
            if (rule.field == "SalePrice" && rule.@operator == "lessthan") return (p => p.SalesPrice < Convert.ToDecimal(value));
       }
}
```

But when for example the rule.value = 50 it returns this:
`{p => (p.SalesPrice > ToDecimal(value(Controllers.PromotionsController+<>c__DisplayClass12_0).value))}`

(This happens when the value is a string, bool, int or decimal)

So my question is why is "Convert.ToDecimal(value)" not resolving to 50 in this function?

Comment: Did you compile your expression?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression-1?view=net-5.0

Comment: Not sure if that's the (whole) issue, but you've got `SalePrice` vs `SalesPrice `.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError sorry I noticed that before and posted the old output but it in unrelated thankfully

Comment: @TimurSidoryuk interesting I didn't find this before, however the output of compile() is {Method = {Boolean lambda_method(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Closure, Product)}}  ALSO an error is thrown on the stack: 
CustomAttributes = 'pred.Method.CustomAttributes' threw an exception of type 'System.NotImplementedException'

Comment: Are you trying to debug expression? I think that you can split 
`return (p => p.SalesPrice < Convert.ToDecimal(value));`
to
`var decimalValue = Convert.ToDecimal(value);
return p.SalesPrice < decimalValue ;`
Maybe runtime information will be helpful.

Comment: @TimurSidoryuk Essentially with this expression output I am putting it into a PredicateBuilder dynamically just as is demonstrated at http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx However once the loop is complete and all the expressions from the GetRule method have been predicated, the Predicate is then put through a queryable .Where clause in order to get items from the database, however this is timing out because I believe the output of the expression is wrong somehow, having difficulty understanding why. Target framework is 4.6.1